# R Table Restructuring

Tags: r

I have a file with the following structure (this is made up data):

```
Manufacturer    Compound          Concentration
hershey         Guar Gum          0.620142402
hershey         Starch                0.224585728
hershey         Glucose               0
hershey         Cocoa Powder          0.000982737
hershey         Citric Acid       0.846410424
hershey         Lactic Acid       0.050681621
hershey         Propylene Glycol      0.998148131
nestle          Guar Gum          0
nestle          Starch                0.857977057
nestle          Glucose               0.497836981
nestle          Cocoa Powder          0.461707584
nestle          Citric Acid       0
nestle          Lactic Acid       0.694891624
nestle          Propylene Glycol      0.367109663
```

How do I restructure it using R into:

```
Compound       Hershey          Nestle
Guar Gum          0.620142402   0
Starch        0.224585728   0.857977057
Glucose       0                 0.497836981
Cocoa Powder      0.000982737   0.461707584
Citric Acid       0.846410424   0
Lactic Acid       0.050681621   0.694891624
Propylene Glycol  0.998148131   0.367109663
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
library("tidyverse")
df2 = spread(df, Manufacturer, Concentration)
```

[Here's an article on reshaping data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)

Comment: Thank you!! I am playing with it right now.